# Shortcut for changing text color

Tags: color, lyx, keyboard

I want to create a shortcut in LyX for changing the color of selected text.

I tried to create a shortcut for "set-color green" or "set-color green green", but none of these worked.

What is the magic word?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Highlight the text and for green use

```
textstyle-update color 4
```

For a general approach for how to figure out the correct command, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: "4" seems to be brown? Where can I find the list of numbers corresponding to the colors?

Comment: For dummies like myself, to create a new shortcut (at least in LyX 2.3.6.1): Go to Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts > Click "New"

Comment: OK I tried and for LyX 2.3.6.1, it seems to be 1 = Black, 2 = White, 3 = Blue, 4 = Brown, 5 = Cyan, 6 = Darkgray, 7 = Gray, 8 = Green, 9 = Lightgray, 10 = Lime, 11 = Magenta, 12 = Olive, 13 = Orange, 14 = Pink, 15 = Purple, 16 = Red, 17 = Teal, 18 = Violet, 19 = Yellow , 20 = Cursor, 21 = Background, 22 = Text, 23 = Selection, 24 = Selected Text, 25 = LaTeX Text, 26 = Previewed Snippet, 27 = Inline Completion, 28 = Non-Unique Inline Completion, 29 = Note Label, 30 = Note Background, etc.

Comment: you, sir, are a fine gentleman, @user24096