# LyX command(s) to insert WYSIWYG horizontal line, for keyboard shortcut

Tags: macros, lyx, rules

Using the menu entry *Insert > Formatting > Horizontal Line* I can insert a WYSIWYG horizontal line into a LyX document.  I want to figure out the internal command(s) used to do this so I can set up a binding to do this via a keyboard shortcut. However, *Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts* doesn't show anything, and the functions listed under *Help > LyX Functions* doesn't show anything either.

I could make a binding to insert the **\hrulefill** LaTeX command, but that wouldn't be WYSIWYG.

Looking in the `.lyx` file, I can see that a WYSIWYG line is done by:

```
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset line
LatexCommand rule
offset "0.5ex"
width "100col%"
height "1pt"

\end_inset


\end_layout
```

However, using a `command-sequence` of multiple `self-insert` to insert those lines one after the other doesn't work.

I'm using LyX version 2.1.2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to View > Messages Pane:

[image]

Then click on the "Settings" tab in the bottom right corner:

[image]

Then click on the "Selected" radio button:

[image]

Then double click on "Action - User commands" at the top so that "no" turns to "yes" (this used to be "User commands" as shown in the screenshot):

[image]

Then click on the "Output" tab:

[image]

Then do the action that you want to copy the shortcut of. In this case, insert your horizontal line. In the output tab at the bottom, you will see:

[image]

This tell us that the correct command is:

```
inset-insert line CommandInset line LatexCommand rule offset "0.5ex" width "100col%" height "1pt" \end_inset
```

Verify that the command is correct by inserting it directly into the mini buffer (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> or View > Toolbars > Command Buffer) at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

Run the command by pressing return. If it has the desired effect, then you know you have the right command and can create the shortcut in the usual way.

Note that you can have one shortcut do multiple commands by using `command-sequence`.

Comment: Thanks!  I did have to drag the message pane divider line up in order for the radio buttons to show, but after that it worked just like you said.

Comment: @MatthewCline good to know. Can you please make a bug report for that at http://www.lyx.org/trac ?

Comment: I think "User commands" is now instead "action - User commands"

Comment: @user182601 thanks! I think that was done so that it would be sorted at the top, since it's the most useful option. I edited in the change.