# What is the keyboard shortcut for inserting URLs in LyX?

Tags: lyx, urls, keyboard

I've looked through the keyboard shortcut documentation, and none of it shows an easy way to create a URL inset in LyX. I know that one can theoretically add a function in preferences, but every time I try to add a key binding, it tells me that `insert-url` and `flex-insert-url` are both not recognizable functions (despite the fact that the documentation says it is). Is there something I'm missing, even in the newest distribution of LyX (2.1.3)? I've also tried looking in the other bind files, but no dice.

Other solution: I know that you can just use `\url{}`, but it would be great to find a solution that allows me to use the URL insets in LyX instead of that dreaded red text.

Comment: Please see my answer to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: Also, where does the documentation say that "insert-url" and "flex-insert-url" are LFUNs?

Answer (score 1):

When you do Insert --> URL the corresponding function is shown briefly in the status bar at the bottom of the LyX window, and it is

```
flex-insert URL
```

Note that it is case-sensitive.