# How to create a hyperlink shortcut in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

A section of my pdf report is a collection of web links with comments. I would like to use a shortcut such as CTRL+K to insert hyperlinks. I couldn't find a hyperlink function under the Lyx Tools / preferences / Shortcuts. Is there a way to add a hyperlink shortcut?

Comment: Does this link help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531 It explains in general how to find the function to use to make a shortcut.

Comment: Yes it helps thank you very much I finally managed to make a shortcut to create a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @scottkosty 's [answer on how to find the name of a Lyx function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531), I selected "User command" debug messages under View > Messages Pane and I found the name of the "Insert Hyperlink" function. Under Tools / preferences / Editing / Shortcuts / "Cursor, Mouse and Editing functions". The function is called: href-insert.

[image: Create a shortcut for the insert href link function]

I then clicked on modify and gave it the shortcut CTRL+K. It replaces another command which I never used.