# Is it possible to define snippets in LyX?

Tags: lyx, code-snippets

While using LyX, I usually have to define some new theorem environments. For example, I define a new environment `rst` to state "Restriction".

```
\newtheorem{rst}{Restriction}
```

In LyX, I need to type `\begin{rst}` and `\end{rst}` to use this environment. Is it possible to define a snippet in LyX to type these for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best would be to create a module or use the local layout. See the current LyX modules for example.

But if you do really just want a keyboard shortcut, go to Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts, click on "New" and choose a shortcut for the following:

```
command-sequence ert-insert; self-insert \begin{rst}; char-forward
```

Comment: Good. Out of curiosity, where did you learn the function `command-sequence ert-insert; self-insert \begin{rst}; char-forward`? Any reference to look at?

Comment: @semibruin see Help > LyX Functions and for how to know which LFUN corresponds to something you do manually, see the answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531