# lyx shortcuts: adding a Table using a shortcut

Tags: lyx, shortcut

I want to add this table using a lyx shortcut:
[image]

The LaTex code is as follows:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\textenglish[variant=american]{state} & \LRE{$P\left[kPa\right]$} & \LRE{$T\left[c\lyxmathsym{\textdegree}\right]$} & \LRE{$v\left[m^{3}/kg\right]$} & \LRE{$u\left[kJ/kg\right]$} & \LRE{$h\left[kJ/kg\right]$} & \LRE{$m\left[kg\right]$} & \LRE{$V\left[m^{3}\right]$} & \textenglish[variant=american]{phase}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
\LRE{$A1$} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\LRE{$A2$} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\LRE{$B1$} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\LRE{$B2$} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

what is the needed shortcut code?

Comment: Do you really want a single keyboard shortcut to add that entire table, with the text?

Comment: You might consider using a clipboard manager like CopyQ (https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ). That is what I use for things like this. You can make a tab called something like "LyX preset tables" and just copy the table (in LyX) and save it in that tab and then whenever you want to paste it go back to that tab. This works well for me with CopyQ on Linux and I would imagine on other platforms as well.

Comment: There's [Is it possible to define snippets in LyX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268459/is-it-possible-to-define-snippets-in-lyx) , but I would imagine that doing multiple lines is not very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but you might want to consider using AutoHotkey to achieve something like this.

AutoHotkey is useful nearly every and any time you want to automate a user action on a PC, because it can emulate any keyboard action.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).