# How to make use of selected text using LyX commands and command sequences?

Tags: lyx, keyboard

I tried assigning two different shortcuts to inserting powers of ten:

```
command-sequence math-insert 10^{ }; up;
math-insert 10^{ }
```

However, if I select some text and then use one of the shortcuts, the selected text is *replaced* instead of being used as the superscript content.

In contrast, a "system-defined" `math-insert` command such as `math-insert \hat` does work both ways: if nothing is selected, a hat is inserted and the cursor is placed under the hat; if any text is selected, it is moved under the hat.

How can I make use of selected text when creating custom commands and command sequences?

EDIT: Curiously, this underbrace sequence works too

```
command-sequence math-insert \underbrace; char-forward; math-subscript;
```

unlike the power-of-ten example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cut/paste for this:

```
command-sequence cut; math-insert 10^{ }; up; paste
```

It has the unfortunate side-effect of modifying your clipboard. Hopefully there will be a [way](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/6604) around this in the future.

Comment: nice workaround! but I'm still wondering why things like `\hat` work flawlessly

Comment: @Sparkler you can. This is just a more general answer for how to use selections. I will give a separate answer that you might prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the text and run the following command:

```
command-sequence math-insert ^; down; self-insert 10; up
```

which would for for both cases.

Comment: It works, but I don't understand how...

Comment: It works just like `math-insert \hat` above. `math-insert` says that the following argument will be a math command to operate on the selected text. The argument `^` says to put in the numerator, whereas `\hat` says to put a hat over the text. By the way you might be interested in this answer which discusses how to figure out which commands to use: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: I meant `self-insert` (I know all the other ones...)

Comment: ah, `self-insert` just inserts the following text directly. You might be interested in Help > LyX Functions which documents the usage of functions and gives examples.