# LyX functions: Nest label from clipboard into inset insert

Tags: macros, lyx, nesting

In writing my thesis in LyX I make frequent use of the **label-copy-as-reference** function - mainly from equations but also with other labels. The labels are however not pasted as **formatted reference** which I think I should use for later flexibility (via the refstyle package). Changing every pasted label manually is not my preferred option ;)

Entering the **inset-insert** function into the mini-buffer

```
inset-insert ref LatexCommand formatted reference "eq:foo" \end_inset
```

I mangaged to paste `eq:foo` in the desired format into my text. How can I nest a function into **inset-insert** which replaces `eq:foo` by a *previously*-copied label (stored in the clipboard)? I was not able to work it out from [How to make use of selected text using LyX commands and command sequences?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281453/how-to-make-use-of-selected-text-using-lyx-commands-and-command-sequences)

PS: Many belated thanks to those behind LyX and this great forum!

Comment: Lets see whether @scottkosty  can help you with this.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could do this within LyX (maybe using "LyX Server"? But that's not really within LyX anyway). You could use a clipboard manager like CopyQ for a macro-type implementation.

Comment: Thanks @scottkosty for your feedback! ...
Learning to use "LyX Server" unfortunately seems beyond my present skills/time budget :-/
Of course, I would be perfectly happy with an alternative way of copying labels and paste them directly as formatted references.
The "cross-reference" dialog keeps the format used last for the next insertion. Is there a way of transferring this to the pasting of cross-references from the clipboard? E.g. any global setting?
For now, I will also try using a keyboard shortcut to `dialog-show ref`.

Comment: Maybe using `command-sequence` to first paste, then `char-backward`, then `inset-modify` with the appropriate arguments? Another answer would be that there is currently an open bug (I believe) asking that the reference is introduced in the last remembered formatting. Maybe this would solve the issue as well.