# Create 1 shortcut for 2 actions

Tags: lyx, shortcut

I want to create a shortcut for a key combination (e.g. Alt+1) for 2 actions:

- textstyle-update color 17
- font-bold

I tried to create a shortcut as

```
textstyle-update color 17; font-bold
```

but it is not working (for some reason it makes the text invisible in lyx with no effect after compilation).

Comment: Hi, welcome. For shortcuts with multiple actions, I think  you need to prepend the functions with `command-sequence`, as in for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281453/

Comment: It is working now, thanks alot

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I suggest to make an answer.

Comment: @scottkosty Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making shortcuts that chains multiple actions, the function has to be prepended with `command-sequence`, so I guess you need

```
command-sequence textstyle-update color 17; font-bold
```