# shortcut for putting a text in a center of a document (at LyX)

Tags: lyx, text

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut for changing the alignment of a text at document (not at math-mode! regular text).

The only option that I know right now, is to do it like this:
[image]
But I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut for changing the alignment.
And if there isn't keyboard shortcut, how can I make one? (For all of the three alignments).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the answer...
What we have to do if we want to change the alignment by keyboard shortcut is this:
[image]

`Alt+A+C` - To the center.
`Alt+A+L` - To the left.
`Alt+A+R` - To the right.

And we can change it by: *Tools->Preferences->Editing->Shortcuts* and at search box we can write `align` and change what we want.

Comment: Another way of finding the functions to change is this method: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a possibility for you:

```
\bind <key combination> <lyx-function>
```

I have it from this [website](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/KeyboardShortcuts)

Comment: Perhaps you should add where this code line is to be used ;-)

Comment: But how I put it at lyx?

Comment: @Yoar in your user folder, there is a user.bind file. To find that file, go to the folder listed in the Help > About location.