# lyx keyboard shortcut for writing a certain word or sentence

Tags: lyx, keyboard

Is there a way to define a shortcut for writing a word. I am tired of writing Ti-6Al-4V all the time in my thesis so I want to define a keyboard shortcut like Shift+t+i and Ti-6Al-4V will be written (not in math mode). This problem is generic for all scientific documents about a certain type of chemical formula or certain type of topic/abbreviation.

Comment: Yes, see my general answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: I am not sure this helps in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new keyboard shortcut in the Preferences with the following command:

```
self-insert Ti-6Al-4V
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to add self-insert. When I add from Preferences it says "Can not insert shortcut to the list". When I created mySC.bind with these lines in it \bind_file "cua"
\bind "M-r t"   "self-insert Ti-6Al-4v" cua commands are indexed but not mine. ps. I tried to run lyx with administrator privileges

Comment: Sorry, now I managed. In the Preferences menu command-sequence self-insert Ti-6Al-4V as function and alt+shift+T as the key works well. But alt+R T does not, anyway. Thanks to all reading or responding for time and effort