# Lyx keyboard shortcut for \underline in math-mode?

Tags: lyx, keyboard

In math-mode, `Alt + M + Underscore` (where underscore is Shift minus in US keyboard layout), produces the LaTex `\underbar{}`, which is textual. I want instead `\underline`. Is there a keyboard shortcut combination in Lyx to produce `\underline`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>. If you want, you can bind that to a shorter shortcut that you create (e.g. 2 key presses instead of 4). See [LyX command(s) to insert WYSIWYG horizontal line, for keyboard shortcut](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531) for how to do that.