# LyX | Replaced Typed Symbol with Macro

Tags: macros, lyx, keyboard

In LyX, I've defined the following Macro:

[image: A screenshot of the macro in LyX]

(it's with `\stackrelthree`)

My question is: is it possible to press on the `=` button on my keyboard, and replace the input to LyX to the macro, instead of the regular '=' character? Assuming that I'm inserting it already in a math environment.

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: My guess is that you can. You can bind any function to the '=' key in tools > preferences > keyboard > shortcut. To figure out the function or command-sequence, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: Great! Do you feel like writing up a detailed answer? (by the way, there is no problem at all with accepting your own answer).

Comment: Would you like to write up an answer here?