# LyX | Create a TeX Shortcut

Tags: lyx, shortcut

In LyX, is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut for inserting a LaTeX environment with some desired LaTeX code in it?

Specifically, I want to insert the TeX code: `\smallskip`.

What I want my shortcut to do is to open a LaTeX environment and write inside of it `\smallskip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the shortcut to the following:

```
command-sequence ert-insert; self-insert \smallskip
```

To see how to find that on your own, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531) answer.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! That did what I wanted, and thanks for the link!