# Is there a keyboard shortcut to duplicate lines in LyX

Tags: lyx, shortcut

I want to duplicate the line I'm currently on without having to copy go down a line and paste.

For example:

```
this is my current line
```

and after one keyboard shortcut

```
this is my current line
this is my current line
```

Comment: I think you can probably make a command-sequence that does it. Take a look here to learn how to make such shortcuts in general: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531  It's a little annoying to learn everything but once you do you can make a shortcut for so many things.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own shortcut in:
Tools -> preferences -> Editing -> shortcuts
and there you can create your own shortcut for this and anything else you will need.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!