# LyX: Create a menu with predetermined topics

Tags: macros, lyx

I'd like to add a menu to LyX with a list of topics that the use can select. Each topic in turn, when selected, will create an itemized list of built-in questions in the document.

I've read about Customization/Installing New Document class, and also in custom insets, but couldn't find a way to do this.

Is this possible? If so, any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: It might be easier to solve the problem by breaking it down into two sub-problems. 1. you need to edit the menus, and 2. you need to construct command-sequences that perform the actions you want. For problem 1, you can edit the menus in the file lib/ui/default.ui (if you have trouble, just search for "default.ui" file on your file system). For problem 2, experiment on the command buffer. Here is a technique to figure out how to make the commands: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot @scottkosty. I checked the instruction in the link and this will take me some experimentation. But I believe is the right way to go. Would you please give me a hint of the coding for implementing say, a list like this one: 1. Introduction: lorem Ipsum...2. Proemium : Lorem Ipsum...

Comment: The following works for me: `command-sequence layout Enumerate; self-insert Introduction: lorem Ipsum...; paragraph-break; self-insert Proemium : Lorem Ipsum...`