# Create a keyboard shortcut for "Apply Last" in LyX

Tags: lyx, shortcut

I would like to make F4 my keyboard shortcut for "Apply Last" in LyX. How do I do this?

The "Apply Last" button looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You should mention what program you are using. (Also I have the suspicion that this question is off-topic as it doesn't pertain to TeX, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Have you checked out: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/KeyboardShortcuts ?

Comment: Do you mean "apply last text style" from the context menu?

Comment: I hope that after the edits, this question is not closed. Since this question is related to LyX, it seems clearly on-topic as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Further, note that there have also been many similar questions.

Comment: @Kenny you might find the following answer useful, which shows you how to get the underlying LFUN. After that, it is just a matter of creating the shortcut in Tools > Preferences. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: @KennyLJ That's great you solved it. Can you please add an answer to this question and accept it? (I know it seems strange to answer your own question, but actually it is encouraged!)

Comment: @KennyLJ Ah yes I hadn't seen that. Thanks for adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts.
2. Font, Layout and Textclasses > Click on "textstyle-apply".
3. Click "Modify", then enter whatever you want the shortcut key to be (for me it was F4).
4. Click "OK" and "Save".

As scottkosty's [answer to another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531)  explains, sometimes (as was the case here), the tricky bit is to find the name of the command. You can do so by following his instructions.