# LyX shortcut for creating an inline inset (specifically - an inline program listing)

Tags: lyx

I can bind the `listing-insert` command to create a program listing (a.k.a a code-formatted block) inset in LyX, but that will make it a *display* style program listing. If I want an inline style program listing, I need to manually open the settings, tick the *Inline listing* checkbox, and click *OK*.

Is there a way to automate this with a keymap, so I can quickly write inline code fragments? I tried looking at the [LyX function list](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyxFunctionList), but all I could see is `inset-settings` that opens the dialog (so I still need to manually tick the checkbox and hit *OK*)

Update: I just noticed `inset-apply` and `inset-modify` which I think may help, but I can't figure out how to use them and can't find info in Google...

Comment: You might find the following answer helpful (it is more general than for the specific question): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: @scottkosty thanks - that helped my find a solution. I'll write an answer.

Comment: Nice, looks good!

Answer (score 1):

I followed @scottkosty's answer in tha other question, and found that when I do it manually LyX is first opening the dialog with `inset-settings` and then sets it to inline with `inset-apply listings true 1 ""`. So I tried this command:

```
command-sequence listing-insert; inset-settings; inset-apply listings true 1
```

And it indeed opened the settings dialog and converted the program listings' style to inline - but it did not close the dialog... And if I removed `inset-settings` the `inset-apply` wouldn't work.

Luckily, I found in the function list help file `inset-modify` which apparently works like `inset-apply` but does not need the settings panel open. So this worked:

```
command-sequence listing-insert; inset-modify listings true 1 ""
```

I also noticed that it only needs the first argument, so my final command is:

```
command-sequence listing-insert; inset-modify listings true
```

Comment: Does not work any more with LyX 2.3 but I found the following fix, `command-sequence listing-insert; char-left; char-left; inset-modify listings true 1 ""`  - the "char-left" are necessary because the cursor is not within the inset, so "inset-modify" is disabled.

Comment: What works best is the `inset-modify` twice; first before moving the cursor, then after. `command-sequence listing-insert; inset-modify listings true 1 ""; char-left; char-left; inset-modify listings true 1 ""` In this way, the inset is created correctly even when you first select some text and then use the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Better yet, add two char-right at the end to support adding empty listing as well:
`command-sequence listing-insert; inset-modify listings true 1 ""; char-left; char-left; inset-modify listings true 1 ""; char-right; char-right;`