# Lyx Shortcut for New Frame and for Pause

Tags: beamer, lyx, mac

I am using `Lyx` on a Mac to make `beamer` slides. In order to start a new frame, I can go to the layout menu dropdown, and choose `Frame`. I can also use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> > <kbd>space</kbd>, and then start typing the word `Frame`. I can do the same for choosing `Pause` from that menu.

Is there a way to setup a keyboard shortcut that generates a new `Frame`, and also one that changes layout to `Pause`?

Comment: Does this answer help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, that answered my question.

Comment: great! I don't think that answer's a duplicate (since it's more general), so I propose that you write an answer.