# using the "enter" kay in lyx shortcuts

Tags: lyx, shortcut

I'm trying to make a shortcut for the beginning and end of the tikz code. how can I separate the lines that are on?

I'm using the code:
command-sequence preview-insert; ert-insert; self-insert \begin{tikzpicture} \end{tikzpicture}

I have tried using: "enter", "Return" but without any luck.

i get this:

[image]

I'm trying to get this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
command-sequence preview-insert; ert-insert; self-insert \begin{tikzpicture}; paragraph-break; paragraph-break; self-insert \end{tikzpicture}
```

For a general approach that you could follow to figure out that `paragraph-break` is was what you wanted, see [LyX command(s) to insert WYSIWYG horizontal line, for keyboard shortcut](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531) (the question does not look related, but the answer is general).