# How to configure a text style "code" keyboard shortcut for Lyx?

Tags: lyx, code

I know the preferences system for Lyx allows keyboard shortcuts to be configured.

However I can't seem to find the right 'command' to set a keyboard shortcut for the text style code, imported from the Logical Markup Module for lyx.

Below is a screenshot showing how that style is applied using the slower GUI method.

I am using macOS Monterey 12.5.1 and lyx latest release 2.3.6.2 and the MaxTEX 2022 distribution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command ("LFUN") is `flex-insert "Code"`.

Here is an answer that gives the general process for finding the underlying LFUN's being run: [LyX command(s) to insert WYSIWYG horizontal line, for keyboard shortcut](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531)