# The LYX code to create custom new shortcuts

Tags: lyx, shortcut

as swp went out of business I am now transitioning to lyx. I am trying to have the same shortcuts in lyx as in swp

for example: \alpha= ctrl+g a etc,

But I was wondering, if I can see the original lyx code to create other shortcuts that are more customized. For this I believe i need to know the lyx syntax.

this code below when included in shortcuts in gui: tools-edit-shortcuts-system and miscallenous gives me underbracets and a box, which is very useful

command-sequence math-insert \underbrace; char-forward; math-subscript;

Is it possible to see the lyx code so that i can add more customized shortcuts like this?

thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: If you want to get into that hornet's nest, maybe Menu `Help` → `Customization` and  `Help` → `Preferences` → `Editing` → `Shortcuts` . Unexplored land for me. I can't say if the pecking is worth it.

Comment: Also see here for how to figure out what GUI action can be translated into underlying LFUNs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: thank you very much. yes i am trying to use this last comment and add shortcuts this way. will update if it works out.