Change default parameters for image insert in LyX
I am using LyX and have to insert many images. For every single image I insert, I am manually setting this with the same values every time:

Is it possible to automate this? Either by changing some setting in LyX for the defaults of this insert image dialogue, or using LyX LFUNs? (I cannot find more documentation about LFUNs unfortunately)

I forget if there is a way to have a "graphics group". That would be idea. If you go the LFUN way, you might find this helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

What is a "graphics group"? Is that a LyX or LaTeX thing?

I think it's a LyX thing, but I forget about it. It seems you found a solution though so that's great!

I found a solution to this combining LyX LFUNs and this answer. Below are the steps:

In the preamble (in LyX go to Document→Settings→LaTeX preamble) add this:

\def\maxwidth#1{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>#1 #1\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}


Now the LFUN inset-insert graphics special width=\maxwidth{\textwidth} will insert an image with the "LaTeX options" value already set, like this:


and with that, the image will keep its own size if it is not wider than the text, otherwise it will be shrink to the text width keeping the aspect ratio.
