how do I make a short-cut which invokes "insert math inline" (typically for use with selected text)?
I'm using LyX 2.4.2.1 on a MacBook Pro (M1, Sonoma) and find that the function I most frequently need to invoke involves inserting a new inline math formula. Typically I start by selecting a symbol (or some rudimentary TeX-able text) and then use my mouse to invoke the function. (Insert/Math/Inline)
It would save a lot of time if I could invoke the function with a shortcut.
I searched and read a bit, found Preferences/Editing/Shortcuts.
The next question is how to find the name of the function I want. (Is there a big table of these? I searched and found https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyxFunctionList .)
The best guess I had was math-insert (I didn't find "inline" anywhere there). However, assigning this to a key did not yield the result I hoped for (it didn't seem to do anything.)
I'd be grateful for pointers.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry. There was a typo, but as I see it my question is pretty clear: I'd like to invoke Insert/Math/Inline as a key-stroke / shortcut (instead of needing to spend valuable seconds each time using the mouse -- or rather the track pad).

Maybe useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

The default keyboard shortcuts for entering math in LyX are Control C M, Control M M, or Command M, depending on the operating system.
If you don't like these, you can assign your own shortcut via Preferences-Editing-Shortcuts: Go to the field that says "Show key-bindings containing" and type "math-mode". There you can define (or reset back to default) a new keyboard shortcut.
For displayed equations, the default keyboard shortcuts are Shift Command M, Control M D, or Command D. You can change them similarly in Preferences by assigning a new shortcut to the command "math-display".
Exiting math mode can be done by simply hitting the Spacebar or Esc.

Thanks, invictus! That's all I needed! (cmd-m on the Mac). (And math-mode as name: I guess I might have guessed that, but since the command was under "insert" I didn't think of it.)
